# Conflict between hand-made symbol and caption environment

Tags: fonts, captions

I tried to create my own hand-made symbol by modifying the standard symbol "{".

It works... but not always. LaTeX barfs at me when my hand-made symbol is inside a caption environment in a figure.

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\bmark}{\raisebox{.53ex}{\rule{.2em}{.1ex}}}
\newcommand{\bopen}{{\ooalign{\{\cr\hfil\bmark\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{My caption. $\bopen$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The macro `\bopen` is "fragile", in the LaTeX-specific meaning of the word. Either `\protect` it or `\robustify` it if you wish to use it in the argument of commands such as `\caption`.

Comment: Off-topic: You use `\textbraceleft` instead of `\{` as the first item in the argument of `\ooalign`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `\protect` the `\ooalign`.

Note: you don't necessarily need math mode for `\bopen` either, nor the extra surrounding group, but I left them intact as the OP had specified.

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\bmark}{\raisebox{.53ex}{\rule{.2em}{.1ex}}}
\newcommand{\bopen}{{\protect\ooalign{\{\cr\hfil\bmark\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{My caption. $\bopen$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```